# Faster 2d-Rendering in java

Tags: java, performance, swing, graphics, java-2d

What is the faster way to render 2d graphics in java. The 2 good way I've seen is Double-Buffering where you create the BufferStrategy like:

```
JFrame f = new JFrame();
f.setSize()
.....
createBufferStrategy(2);
```

The other method I've seen is with the createImage method.

```
Image dbimage = createImage(....);
Graphics g = dbimage.getGraphics();
....
```

Those are the two I've seen. Which is the fastest? Are there better ways? Please don't tell me to get add-on libraries because I'm aware those exist. Thank you in advance...

Comment: Most importantly: have you measured it? Which one was fastest?

Comment: I don't know which one is fastest... that's why I'm asking...

Comment: I think the biggest problem you're going to have with trying to determine this is the difference in hardware and OS implementations. There are a lot of tweaks you can pass into the Java2D rendering engine (we used some to correct issues ATI Radeon cards), so while approach may work for a particular hareware group/OS, it may not work for another, in general

Comment: In response to @Strelok's suggestion, record the start and end time (System.currentTimeMillis()) of each operation and compare them. That will give you your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first snippet [BufferStrategy] is the fastest and the recommended way of doing 2d rendering in java. With it you can take advantage of hardware rendering or optimized software rendering. The performance is highly noticeable when you are doing fullscreen 2d rendering. For example, you could benefit from page flipping that updates the screen by a very simple operation consisting of changing a pointer to a buffer. Other benefit is to have buffers in video memory.